# An algorithm to get the next weekday set in a bitmask

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've got this small question - given a bitmask of weekdays (e.g., `Sunday = 0x01, Monday = 0x02, Tuesday = 0x04`, etc...) and today's day (in a form of `Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, Tuesday = 3`, etc...) - what's the most elegant way to find out the next day from today, that's set in the bitmask? By elegant I mean, is there a way to do this without if/switch/etc..., because I know the non-elegant way?

**Edit** I probably should've mentioned (to make this more clear) that the variable holding the bitmask can have several of the days set, so for example (roughly):

```
uDay = Sunday | Monday;
today = Tuesday;
```

I need to get "Sunday"

Comment: BTW, does "next" mean "today or later", or "strictly later than today"? (E.g with "uDay = Sunday | Tuesday; today = Tuesday;", what should it say?)

Comment: missed this comment :) next = today or later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int getNextDay(int days_mask, int today) {
   if (!days_mask) return -1; // no days set
   days_mask |= days_mask << 7; // duplicate days into next week
   mask = 1 << (today % 7); // keep track of the day
   while (!(mask & days_mask)) {
      mask <<= 1;
      ++today;
   }
   return today % 7;
}
```

So that's just one if at the beginning and while loop. How's that?

**Edit:** I just realized there was a degenerate case where if the use passes today>=14 (or greater than the highest bit set) the while loop becomes infinite. The (today % 7) on line 4 fixes this case.

And if I may grouse (light-heartedly) about the other version getting the checkmark, my version only have 2 modulus calls, while the checked solution will have a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 6 modulus calls.

Also, the comment about does the function return "today" if today is set is interesting. If the function should not return today unless today is the only day in the set would require that you pre-increment today on line 3 of my solution.

Comment: the way you duplicate the bits and then go along is pretty clever :)

Comment: I gave the checkmark because he was first with a solution - sorry :) I'll check all code when I get to a compiler and will decide on the final mark then. I appreciate your time and effort on this.

Comment: Hmm, actually I don't think it works (or I messed something up) - for example, if days_mask = 0x14 and today = 3, the function returns 4, when I expect it to return 3 (or 5).

Comment: 4 is 0-based 5th day of week. 0x14 has 0-based bits 2 and 4 set. Rereading the requirements, I see I need +1 in my return: return today%7 + 1.

Comment: yep, in my case Sunday is 1-based.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any extra variables at all. The simplest idea -- start with "tomorrow", look at successive days until you find a day in the mask -- is also the most elegant to implement. The trick to doing it nicely is to think of the days as Sunday=0, Monday=1 and so on (only inside this function). Then, "today" is actually `t-1` (where t is the input to the function, so it goes from 1 to 7), and "tomorrow" is `(t-1+1)%7` i.e `t%7`, etc.

This is simple and has been tested against litb's code exhaustively, just to be sure :-)

```
int getNextDay(int m, int t) {
  if((m&127)==0) return t;          //If no day is set, return today
  t=t%7;                            //Start with tomorrow
  while((m&(1<<t))==0) t = (t+1)%7; //Try successive days
  return t+1;                       //Change back to Sunday=1, etc.
}
```

Edit: If you want "next" to mean "today or later", then the "t=t%7" line should be changed to `t=t-1` or `--t`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question this way:

```
// returns t (today) if no weekday is set in the mask.
int getNextDay(int m, int t) {
    int i, idx;
    for(i = 0, idx=t%7; i<7 && !((1<<idx)&m); i++, idx=(idx+1)%7)
        /* body empty */ ;
    return (i == 7) ? t : (idx + 1);
}

// getNextDay(8|2, 2) == 4, getNextDay(64, 2) == 7
// getNextDay(128, 2) == 2
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll need to calculate what it does and I'll see if it'll work the way I need it to :)

Comment: I'm just doing this on paper at the moment :) But shouldn't getNextDay(128, 2) return 5?

Comment: 128 is   10000000 , that is, for all weekdays, we have zero bits. there can't be a next-day then. in that case, i return today

Answer (score 1):

> By elegant I mean, is there a way to do this without if/switch/etc...

You bet! Whether that will mean 'elegant' in any usual sense, well:

```
static unsigned next_day_set (unsigned today, unsigned set) {
  unsigned arev = bitreverse (highest_bit_set (bitreverse ((set << 7) | set)
                                               & (bitreverse (today) - 1)));
  return ((arev >> 7) | arev) & 0x7f;
}
```

That's assuming you have 'elegant' functions to reverse the bits in a word and find the leftmost bit set -- see [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/). If you represented the weekday bits in the reverse order, it'd be simpler and actually even sort of elegant for real, assuming I didn't screw up:

```
enum {
  Sunday  = 1 << 6
  Monday  = 1 << 5
  Tuesday = 1 << 4,
  /* etc */
  Saturday = 1 << 0
};

static unsigned next_day_set (unsigned today, unsigned set) {
  unsigned a = highest_bit_set (((set << 7) | set) & ((today << 7) - 1));
  return ((a >> 7) | a) & 0x7f;
}
```